# Task.Await within loop not acting as intended

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a class that awaits an asynchronous thread to return. What I do is launch a while loop and check every second where it's at.

```
public class AsychronousThingy
{
   public bool IsComplete{get;private set;}
   public string Result {get;private set;}
   public void StartDoingThings(){
       IsComplete = false;
       // kick of an asynchronous thread to do stuff...
   }
   private void OnComplete(){
       IsComplete = true;
       Result = "magical result";
   }
}
public class ActionExecutor{
    public async Task<CustomThingyTaskResult> DoStuff(){
        var thing = new AsychronousThingy();
        thing.StartDoingThings();

        // this returns instantly...?
        while(!thing.IsComplete){
             await Task.Delay(1000);
        }

        // do stuff once the 'thing' is complete.
        return new CustomThingyTaskResult(thing.Result);
    }
}
class Program{
    public static void Main(){
         var exec = new ActionExecutor();
         var returnValue = await exec.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

I'm unsure why it is returning instantly. Is this an issue - can you not use Task.Delay inside a loop? Odd.

I am sure that this is returning before it is complete as when I `console.writeline` from the OnComplete event of my async class it actually completes *after* my main method has finished.

Comment: `DoStuff` should return a `Task`

Comment: Apologies it does... very bad pseudo example. Updated.

Comment: Your updated code doesn't compile, because `await` can't be used in `Main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Main()` function is `void`. As a result, after first hit to actual `async` action (in your example it is `await Task.Delay(1000)`) it returns control to its caller.
So, you can change the signature of `Main()` function as follows:

```
public static async Task Main() {...}
```

And then await on it.

Or, as alternative, you may not use `async` keyword on it and use old Wait/Result:

```
public static void Main()
{
...
var returnValue = exec.DoStuff().Result;
// Or, if there is a SynchronizationContext
returnValue = Task.Run(() => exec.DoStuff()).Result; // This may prevent dead locks that can occur in previous line
}
```

Comment: This is actually close to the correct answer - my example is a pseudo example; but the main problem was that the parent class's parent class (ie on above my example above's `Main` method) was not running as a task. Fixing this resolved it and made the method maintain control at the `await`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `DoStuff()` is async, it finishes asynchronously when called. This explains why the `main` method has already returned when the asynchronous action completes. However, since `DoStuff` returns `void`, you cannot `await` it as you would normally do. You can change the return type to `Task` though, and then `await` it.

There is nothing wrong about awaiting in a loop, except that it is more efficient to use events (or other synchronization mechanisms). Also, `AsynchronousThingy` could likely be formulated in terms of a `Task` as well :-)

Comment: You should be using `Task` instead - `void` cannot be awaited. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524395.aspx#BKMK_VoidReturnType